# Type-Safety with optional fields in a data class for JSON

Tags: json, rest, kotlin

I am building a REST-API in Kotlin and I am trying to write my data classes in such a way that I can also use them for accessing the API.
I plan to have a common "data library", which will be shared between the server and the client using the API.

This works great so far, but now I need to model optional fields in the JSON responses. For example: I have a `User` object (accessible via the `/user/{id}` endpoint in typical REST fashion). Now, you do not always need for example the user's "about me" text, so by default it is not included in the response. However if you specify the `"aboutme"` field (`/user/{id}?fields=aboutme`) it will be included in the response.

I could model the data class as follows:

```
data class User(id: UUID, name: String, aboutMe: String?)
```

But now I have to do a null check on the field every time I access it, even when it's obviously not null. I would like to create a type-safe frontend for the API so that when I do, for example, `myCoolApi.getUser({id}, User::aboutMe)` I will get a `User` object where `aboutMe` is not nullable. I could achieve this with generics somehow, I think, but that would get very verbose as soon as there are multiple optional fields involved.

I am interested in any suggestions.

As per request, I will add a bit more code to show what I am after.

```
class MyApi {

    fun getUser(id: UUID, vararg fields: KProperty1<User, *>): User

}

// usage:

val myApi: MyApi = TODO()
val userId: UUID = TODO()
val aboutMe: String = myApi.getUser(userId).aboutMe // does not compile, aboutMe field not specified so aboutMe is nullable
val aboutMe2: String = myApi.getUser(userId, User::aboutMe).aboutMe // compiles, about me field was specified and thus cannot be null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve by creating multiple constructor for data class as per mention in documentation of [Class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

```
//data class User(val id: String, val name: String, val aboutMe: String? = null)

data class User(val id: String, val name: String) {
    constructor(id: String, name: String, aboutMe: String? = null) : this(id, name)
}
```

or you can use @JvmOverloads to create constructor based on passed arguments. You can find more about [@JvmOverloads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/)

```
data class Users @JvmOverloads constructor(val id: String, val name: String, val aboutMe: String? = null)
```

Comment: I know about the `!!` operator, it is precisely what I would _not_ like to do, because it does not actually offer type-safety. Like I said in my question, I would like `getUser` to return something with a nullable `aboutMe` in case I don't pass in the `aboutMe` field and return something with a non-null `aboutMe` if I do pass it in. I.e.: `api.getUser({id}, User::aboutMe).aboutMe` is non-null but `api.getUser({id}).aboutMe` is nullable.

Comment: Then set default value for about me `data class User(id: UUID, name: String, aboutMe: String? = "Default Value")` or you can return default value if value is null `myCoolApi.getUser({id}, User::aboutMe ?: "This value returned if aboutMe is Null")`

Comment: I am sorry, but you do not understand my problem. `User::aboutMe` is a property reference, it will never be null. What can be null is the _value_ of `aboutMe` itself, but if `?fields=aboutme` is passed to the API, it can _not_ be null. I want to express that in a type-safe way. I do not need default values.

Comment: Based on your edit: How do I even use these two classes? I'd have to make my method return `Any`, which is not very nice...

Comment: @diesieben07 can you provide whole implications with your class and methods ?

Comment: @diesieben07 Kindly look in this articles may be it will helps you. [CRUD API](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/04/crud-operations-spring-rest-resources-kotlin/)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options to try:

For optional values you could use a non-nullable property with a default value as in

```
data class User (val id: Long, val name: String, val aboutMe: String = "")
```

Another alternative is possible if you can forgo the data class and instead use a regular class that supports inheritance as follows.

```
open class User (val id: Long, val name: String, val aboutMe: String)

class User_  (id: Long, name: String, aboutMe: String?) 
       : User(id, name, aboutMe ?: "")

class MyCoolApi {

    fun getUser(id: Long): User {

        // do you db lookup or something like that
        // val name = ... from db
        // val aboutMe = ... from db
        return User_(id, name, aboutMe)
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are both options I have tried, but they do not solve my primary problem. If I pass in the `aboutMe` field _that alone_ should be enough for the method to return a user with a non-nullable `aboutMe`. In your example I still have to do a (potentially unsafe) cast to `User_` after calling the method.

Comment: calling User_(id, name, aboutMe) in my example is not unsafe. If the aboutMe arg is null, it will still work.  

Your statement  "If I pass in the aboutMe field that alone should be enough for the method to return a user with a non-nullable aboutMe" - is not clear. Are you saying that aboutMe is a lookup key?

Comment: Passing in `aboutMe` will tell the REST-Api "please also return me the aboutMe text", hence it cannot be null in the returned `User` object. I want that to be reflected in the type system.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are asking is a `User` class to have each of its property in both optional & required variants. I'm not sure if this is possible with a single `User` class. One possibility is that you would have to come up with many variations of `User` each having different combinations of those optional/required properties (similar to what  @Grzegorz is suggesting).

Comment: Well, it would work with generics: `data class User<AM : String?>(val id: UUID, val aboutMe: AM)`. It would just get a bit tedious, but maybe that's what I have to do.

Comment: Well, in your example `<AM: String?>` means that the property will be optional and thus can be null. How are you going to ensure non-null behavior? I any case, I'm also curious on what that full generics solution is.

Comment: `AM` is a type parameter. `User<String>` will have a non-nullable property `aboutMe` of type `String` where as `User<String?>` has a nullable property `aboutMe` of type `String?`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to use [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html):

```
sealed class ApiUser(val id: UUID, val name: String)

class ApiUserPlain(id: UUID, name: String) :
        ApiUser(id, name)

class ApiUserAbout(id: UUID, name: String, val aboutMe: String) :
        ApiUser(id, name)

fun getUser(userId: Long): ApiUserPlain {
    return ApiUserPlain(UUID.randomUUID(), userId.toString())
}

fun getUser(userId: Long, about: String): ApiUserAbout {
    return ApiUserAbout(UUID.randomUUID(), userId.toString(), about)
}

fun test() {
    val userId = 2L
    val aboutMe: String = getUser(userId).aboutMe // does not compile
    val aboutMe2: String = getUser(userId, "about").aboutMe // compiles
}
```

Another way would be to use [multiple interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html):

```
interface ApiUserPlain {
    val id: UUID
    val name: String
}

interface ApiUserAbout {
    val aboutMe: String
}

class PlainUser(
        override val id: UUID,
        override val name: String
) : ApiUserPlain

class AboutUser(
        override val id: UUID,
        override val name: String,
        override val aboutMe: String
) : ApiUserPlain, ApiUserAbout

fun getUser(userId: Long): PlainUser {
    return PlainUser(UUID.randomUUID(), userId.toString())
}

fun getUser(userId: Long, about: String): AboutUser {
    return AboutUser(UUID.randomUUID(), userId.toString(), about)
}

fun test() {
    val userId = 2L
    val aboutMe: String = getUser(userId).aboutMe // does not compile
    val aboutMe2: String = getUser(userId, "about").aboutMe // compiles
}
```

Both sealed classes and interfaces allow you to accomplish compile time verification that you are not accessing a non present `aboutMe` property. However, depending on the extension of your API you might be better of with interfaces which allow easier composition. Both methods can be accessed easily through the [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) when you get a generic/parent parameter in a function.

Comment: Yes, the general concept of this does work. However your overloading of the `getUser` method is problematic. There is not just one of these fields, but potentially multiple. With your version I would have to create all possible combinations as both a class and a corresponding method. That's not very practical :(